# switching screen with libGDX on android is slow, but instant on PC?

Tags: android, button, screen, libgdx

I am trying to change my screen once the button is pressed, which is working pretty well on my PC, there is no delay, and once the button is pressed, the scene instantly changes and presents the new one, however, when i tried to work my app on my android devices (LG G2X & Galxy S 3) I faced the following issue;

After pressing the button, there is a slight delay of about 1-2 seconds and only then it changes to my called screen.

I am disposing all of the resources in the dispose method, and I am also calling the dispose method from my `hide` function since i don't want to hold extra screens in the background and waste memory.

here is my button:

```
private TextButton bPlay;

@Override
public void show() {
....

bPlay = new TextButton("PLAY", skin);
        bPlay.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
                        .setScreen(new DifficultySelectorScreen());

            }
        });
        bPlay.pad(15);

....
}
```

I add it to my table, and then to the stage, and once its clicked, it moves me to select the difficulty for the game.

now its not only this button that has a delay on it, but every button i try to use.

Comment: you might be loading some assets while swicthing the screen... this takes time on android but works instantly on desktop.

Comment: @VikalpJain yes, im loading a little bit in the `show` function, one Json file and one atlas, and also setting it all up in there, i was suspecting this might have been my issue from the beginning, but if i do not need to initialize everything there, where am i supposed to?

Comment: one atlas? How big is this atlas, you have to remember most android devices are very resource constrained and minor things can quickly turn into major performance bottlenecks. Are you using the AssetManager class provided by libgdx? It allows resource loading in the background.

Comment: no, im using a simple 16x16 pixel atlas... its extremely small.. its just for the menu, i was working straight with OpenGL-ES 2.0 up to last week and decided to change to libgdx since i heard its easier and more powerful, in my GLES20 version i loaded over 10 sprite sheets... each one around 512x512, so i do not see how this small one effected it that much 0.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found out what the problem was... every time the screen changes, it re-loads the same `skin` and `atlas`, so I made an AssetManager to handle this, I made it load the assets needed for the main menu while it presents the splash screen, and for the game itself while disposing the menu assets and loading the game assets in a transition page similar to the splash screen.